# VB.NET SQL Search from table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, search

I've created the table: "tblInterni" on my sql database and made so that I can see it on a datagridview.
I am now making a search function so that if I search for a name it loads everyone with that name in the datagridview, but the query I made isn't working.

```vb
Private Sub Home_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=SRV-SQL;Initial Catalog=dbTest;User ID=pwdDb;Password=pwdDb")
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblInterni", conn)
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(table)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = table

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim searchQuery As String = "SELECT * From tblInterni WHERE name like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
End Sub
```

[form graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7amn.png)

Comment: Where are you executing your searchQuery string?

Comment: searchQuery is to filter the data but its doing nothing

Comment: Why would it do anything?  All you're doing is creating a `String`.  You have to do something with that `String` if you want it to affect anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you are retrieving all the data when the form loads, what you should be doing is binding your `DataTable` to the `DataGridView` via a `BindingSource` and then filtering that data by setting the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource`.

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MyTable", "connection string here")
        Dim table As New DataTable

        adapter.Fill(table)

        BindingSource1.DataSource = table
        DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    BindingSource1.Filter = $"MyColumn LIKE '%{TextBox1.Text}%'"
End Sub
```

Note that the `BindingSource` would be added in the designer, just like the grid.

This is still not ideal though.  If the user wants to type several characters in order to filter then this code will modify the filter several times unnecessarily and actually slow them down.  A better idea is to use a `Timer` to add a small delay before filtering that resets each time they make a change.  That way, if they type several characters quickly enough, the filter will only change after the last character.

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MyTable", "connection string here")
        Dim table As New DataTable

        adapter.Fill(table)

        BindingSource1.DataSource = table
        DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    'Start/reset the filter timer.
    Timer1.Stop()
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    BindingSource1.Filter = $"MyColumn LIKE '%{TextBox1.Text}%'"
End Sub
```

You can experiment a bit with the `Interval` of the `Timer` but you should find that something around 300 milliseconds should mean that filtering still feels fast enough but typing at a reasonable speed should avoid most unnecessary intermediate filters.

Comment: How about a Search button?

Comment: How about you don't introduce some new requirement that wasn't mentioned at all in your question?

Comment: Merry Christmas, John. Maybe because TextChanged is not a great place for code like this. Putting the code in a Search button is cleaner, I my never humble opinion. :-) As a user I would certainly prefer a button rather than a less than 1/3 second to decide if I put in enough text. It wasn't my question, BTW.

Comment: @Mary, ah, I didn't look at the name so didn't realise that you weren't the OP. The OP didn't ask for a `Button` so I didn't provide code for a `Button`. There are plenty of apps that provide live filtering like this so there's nothing wrong with it. The use of a `Timer` alleviates one potential issue. That said, filtering is filtering and my answer provides filtering code.  That code can be moved to a different event handler if desired.

Comment: Yes, filtering code is saved to my code file. Thanks. Glad to know that the Timer is a common mechanism used to temper the TextChanged event.